# Import database too long

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to optimize sql dump postgres database importation.
My dumps weights about 1.5Go and it takes about 2 hours to import schema and data.
My architecture is dockerized.

Did you faced this kind of issue ?

Do you advice to run more parallel postgres jobs or to remove some useless tables ?

[EDIT]
I am using the classic craft cli command :

```
craft db/backup
```

All the best,

Emilie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Craft won’t backup the data in these tables:

https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/db/Connection.php#L215-L222

So those could be good candidates if you're looking to exclude data.

You don't say how the backup was make (psql vs. pg_dump, single line inserts vs. multiline, etc.), but generally speaking, using [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) with `--format=custom` so it does a binary dump and pairing it with `pg_restore` is going to be faster than plain text based dumps to restore.

Comment: True, these tables are already empty : 
assetindexdata, 
assettransformerindex, 
cache, 
sessions, 
templatecaches, 
templatecachecriteria, 
templatecacheelements. 
I will use pg_dump which is more low level with more options. Thanks !